# Wrong value binding with Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Problem description**

I'm currently working on a Wizard mechanism in our ASP.NET MVC application. However, I've faced a problem while trying to bind model in the view. In short:

I've got a wizard model which looks more or less like this:

```
class WizardViewModel {
    public IList<StepViewModel> Steps { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Each step except for last has got its own model. The last step (summary) takes whole `WizardStepModel` and is used only to display data (via disabled controls). Displaying values from all steps leads to this kind of code in the view:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
       m => ((ConcreteStepModel)Model.Steps[0]).SelectedValue,
       ((ConcreteStepModel)Model.Steps[0]).SelectList,
       new { disabled = "disabled" }
 )
```

The code works, but continuous casting base step model to a concrete class only to get the value:

1. Is uncomfortable,
2. makes code less readable.

**What I tried to do?**

I thought that I could create an alias for each step:

```
@{
    ConcreteStepModel stepOne = (ConcreteStepModel)Model.Steps[0];
}
```

And then:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
       m => stepOne.SelectedValue, stepOne.SelectList, new { disabled = "disabled" }
 )
```

It works for most of controls, but not for DropDownList. For some reason, value of the dropdown is bound incorrectly and shows first option instead of the selected one.

**Question**

Is there another way which I could use for creating some kind of aliases for steps from the wizard so that I don't have to perform casting each time I need to get a value? Or maybe I am doing something wrong? I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => stepOne.SelectedValue, ...)` generate `<select name="stepOne.SelectedValue" ... >` and your model does not have a complex property named `stepOne` which contains a property named `SeledctedValue` so binding fails.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It seems strange to me, because when I'm using other Html.[...]For methods, it works. The only control which is not working is DropDownList. That's why I asked a question - I'd like to know if there is a way to work around the problem

Comment: It does not work for any other controls if you were to use `m => stepOne.AnyPropertyAtAll` :)

Comment: Well, you can believe me or not, but it does :-) Maybe it won't be bound correctly in controller, but it doesn't have to, because I'm storing models in session. What I want to do is to let them be displayed in the view - and that works for labels, textboxes, radio buttons, etc.

Comment: Of course it wont be bound correctly in the controller - so it does not work! But what is the point of creating form controls if you have no intention of editing/saving the data?

Comment: My bad - radio buttons also don't work :-) I get your point and partially I agree. So... I thought of one possible solution then. I could create a partial view for each step and pass model to this partial. This way I avoid casting, but I get more files - which is not good when I have e.g. two properties to display. Do you have any other idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112898/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-pjdev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 'last step' is just a summary and presumably used as a final 'confirmation step' before saving to the database, then you should not be generating disabled form controls for your properties. It would be rendering anywhere 2-5 times the html that is necessary which will just degrade performance.

Instead just generate the value of the property as text, for example

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Steps[0].SomeProperty)</div>
    <div class="field-value">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Steps[0].SomeProperty)</div>
</div>
```

and use the class names to style the layout (and the result would no doubt save a lot of screen space as well).

For the dropdownlist properties, you would need to add an additional property associated with the selected text, so in addition to `public int SelectedValue { get; set; }` used in the edit view, you would include an associated `public string SelectedText { get; set; }` property for the 'final step' view.

It also appears from your code that `StepViewModel` is an abstract base class and you have a concrete class for each 'step'. If that is the case, then it would be better for your `WizardViewModel` to contain properties for each step

```
public class WizardViewModel
{
    public Step1Model Step1 { get; set; }
    public Step2Model Step2 { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

which means if you really did want to generate form controls, it would not be be necessary to cast the type. The code would just be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Step1.SelectedValue, Model.Step1.SelectList, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it needs some further modifications (I am refactoring existing code), the idea with displaying values instead of using disabled controls seems the best in this case. 

In regards to storing concrete steps in WizardViewModel - my point was to create a simple, generic mechanism, which could be used in many wizards over the application. That's why I have a list with steps instead of properties with concrete steps. Still, modifying your idea a bit, I could create a concrete model for each wizard and create getters which return concrete steps from the list.